# Quelle est la signification de "Ne prends pas le train pour la Cordillère"?

Tags: sens

Je suis anglaise et je ne comprends pas cette phrase tirée du livre *Et soudain tout change* de Gilles Legardinier : "Ne prends pas le train pour la Cordillère".

Je sais que la Cordillère est une chaîne de montagnes mais je suis un peu perdue.

Voici le contexte :

> "Lucie, sauve-toi […] ! Ne prends pas le train pour la Cordillère, la ligne est effondrée…"

Comment: Il faudrait être plus précis pour dire exactement ce que tu ne comprends dans la phrase ? Tu as l'air de bien te débrouiller en français donc je suppose que tu comprends « pendre le train ». Est-ce le sens de  « pour » ici ?« Pour » indique la direction ou la destination du train (in English you'd say "to").  As-tu essayé de chercher dans un dictionnaire ? Ou un traducteur ? [Par exemple](https://www.deepl.com/translator#fr/en/Ne%20prends%20pas%20le%20train%20pour%20la%20Cordill%C3%A8re).

Comment: Merci pour ta réponse. Oui, je comprends les mots mais je ne comprends pas le sens dans le contexte, je suis en train de traduire le phrase vers l'anglais et je ne veux pas mettre simplement "Don't take the train to the Cordillera"

Comment: Il n'y a pas de sens caché, il faut donc dire avec précision ce qui te pose un problème de compréhension. Et un seul point par question.

Comment: Je ne comprends pas pourquoi une personne dirait le phrase, pourquoi la Cordillère?

Comment: Mais dans ta question tu n'écris pas "...pourquoi la Cordillère?" Si tu veux savoir pourquoi « la Cordillère »  est dans ce texte, on ne peut pas savoir, il faudrait en lire plus. Ça ne peut être qu'un  lieu, après il faut le contexte de l'histoire pour en savoir plus.

Comment: T'as raison, pardon. C'était difficile pour moi de l'expliquer en français me je vais essayer. La personne parle d'une fille qui veut aider une autre fille, mais l'autre fille est un peu egoïste et tout ça, donc je pense que la fille qui parle veut dire "ne l'aider pas...c'est une mauvaise idée.." etc.?

"Même si mon instinct me pousse à réconforter ceux qui ne vont pas bien, je ne vais pas retomber dans le même panneau. Et là, tout à coup, regardez qui approche : Lucie. Sauve-toi, pauvre petite créature ! Tout de suite ! Ne prends pas le train pour la Cordillère, la ligne est effondrée"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128778/discussion-between-none-and-ad95).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Il n'y a pas de sens caché dans cette phrase.

On trouve plus tôt dans le livre :

> Pourtant, ce n’est pas son nom le pire, c’est sa tête. Ce n’est pas qu’elle soit moche, mais je parie qu’elle se prépare sans même se regarder dans une glace. C’est peut-être un vampire. Cela expliquerait qu’elle soit incapable de se voir dans un miroir. C’est sans doute pour cela que, régulièrement, ses boutons de gilet son décalés. Ce matin, je pense qu’elle s’est en plus maquillée dans un train qui déraillait. **Pour venir, elle est passée par la Cordillère des Andes, et la voie s’est effondrée parce que Léo et Axel ont fait sauter un pont.** Seule rescapée : Mme Gerfion et sa tête d’épouvantail.

> ([Gilles LEGARDINIER – Et soudain tout change](http://gloewen.canalblog.com/archives/2014/02/13/29198517.html))

Comment: Je venais de trouver le texte en ligne et c'est ce que je venais de signaler au PO dans le chat. Je n'ai pas tout lu (pas l'air folichon comme lecture !) mais je pense que c'est toute une histoire qui se passe dans la tête de la narratrice.

Comment: @None Oui, c'est bien sûr imaginaire. Au début du livre : *À quelques pas devant, Axel et Léo marchent en discutant de la meilleure façon d’effondrer un pont de chemin de fer. Allez comprendre les garçons…*